# filter code of using python

Tags: python, filter

```
def process_data_file (filename):

    csvfile = open(data_file_name, "rU")
    header = csvfile.readline() #choose entries except the first line
    total = 0  #This is the total max temperature in each file
    length = 0  #This is how many elements in each column of max temperature in each file
    s = 0       # This variable is used to count how many days are 37+
    year_test = 0  #This variable is used to test whether the input year is in the year list of file
    year_memories = 0  #This variable is used to memories the previous year input in order to seperate different years into different groups with their own elements
    total_2 = 0  # This variable is used to sum the total max temperature in each groups
    i = 0         # This is used to count how many days are 37+ in each groups
    length_2 = 0  # This is used to count how many elements in each column of max temperature in each groups

    for entry in csvfile:#defin the working area
        filter_test = accept_entry (entry)
        if filter_test == True:


            entry_without_newline = entry[:-1]          #list all element in this working area
            value = entry_without_newline.split(",")     #use split function to transfer string to list
            value_1 = float(value[5])                     # catch up the max temperature elements to do calculation
            total = total + value_1
            length += 1 
            average = total/length
            if value_1 > 37:
                s = s + 1
            else:
                s = s
    #discuss different situations and divide into several groups by using for loop
    #each different groups will print  a set of unique value
            year = int(value[2])                         
            year_test = year
            if year_test == year_memories or year_memories == 0:     
                year_memories = year_test
                total_2 = total_2 +value_1
                length_2 = length_2 + 1

                if value_1 > 37.0:
                    i = i + 1
                else:
                    i = i
                    average_2 = total_2/length_2
            else:
                print(year_memories, "average = ", average_2)
                print("     number of 37+ days = ",i)
                total_2 = value_1
                length_2 = 1                              #The length here is one because in the loop, year_memories != year_test only once and in next loop
                                                      #year_memories = year_test,so length should be 1
                i = 0
                if value_1 > 37.0:
                    i = i +1
                year_memories = year_test
                print(year_memories, "average = ", average_2)
                print("     number of 37+ days = ",i)
            print("average =",average)
            print("number of 37+ days: ",s)



    #/........................................................................................................     


    if accept_entry(entry_without_newline):
        pass
            #csvfile.close()

def accept_entry (entry):

    entry_without_newline = entry[:-1]          #list all element in this working area
    value = entry_without_newline.split(",")
    variable_year = value[2]
    variable_month = value[3]
    variable_days = value[4]
    variable_temperature = value[5]
    variable_quality = value[7]
    if variable_year == "" or variable_month == "" or variable_days == "":
        return False
    else:
        return True
    if variable_temperature > 50.7 or variable_temperature < -23:
        return False
    else:
        return True
    if variable_quality == Y:
        return True
    else:
        return False







if __name__ == "__main__":

        data_file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
        process_data_file(data_file_name)
```

This program is used to

1. If any of the fields year, month, day or maximum temperature is empty, discard the entry.
2. If the quality field is not a 'Y', discard the entry.
3. Discard the entry if the maximum temperature is unrealistic.

but when i run it, it will only run a part of this program and siad

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\1730 assignment\task 2(final_draft)(1) (1).py", line 100, in <module>
    process_data_file(data_file_name)
  File "E:\1730 assignment\task 2(final_draft)(1) (1).py", line 23, in process_data_file
    value_1 = float(value[5])                     # catch up the max temperature elements to do calculation
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "
```

can anyone help me to figure out what"s the problem is or how to imprrove it ?

Comment: It is throwing an error here `value_1 = float(value[5])`. What happens if you `print value[5]`? Does it make sense to convert that to a `float`, in other words, is it a string with only numerics?

Comment: yes, that is the problem, when i run it, part of this row will be printed but the same error as above, suddently, it said could not convert string to float, how can i fix it

Comment: put the print before `value_1 = float(value[5])` to see what is causing the error

Comment: there is a data missing, but I think my code below is goring to fix the problem if any data missing, maybe my code below did not work?

Comment: the best thing you can do is show the problem line and the values that is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

check the lines

```
value = entry_without_newline.split(",")     #use split function to transfer string to list
value_1 = float(value[5])
```

(maybe print out value to see what is going wrong)

It looks like your data isn't lining up - hence python is trying to convert a string (held in value[5]) to a float

Comment: there is a data missing, but I think my code below is goring to fix the problem if any data missing, maybe my code below did not work?

Comment: i suppose it would fix it for the case of a gap but what about the case value[5] =" 5" (i.e an insertion of a gap) why not do something like if type(variable_year)==str: